# Prevent angular modal popup closing while clicking on the page when use angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I am using directive for modal pop up

```
mymodule.directive('modalDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true, 
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.width)
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
      if (attrs.height)
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
        if (attrs.overflow)
        scope.dialogStyle.overflow = attrs.overflow;
      scope.hideModal = function() {

        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'><i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"// See below
  };
});
```

Its working fine but when i click anywhere in my page modal pop up gets closed.how can i prevent from it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `<div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>` overlay element with [`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive which calls `hideModal` on click event. 
Removing this should prevent the popup from closing.

Comment: hi,Actually my probelm is if i click cancel button or when i cal hideModal() its working fine but if i click anywhere in my page except  cancel button or when i cal hideModal() modal pop up getting closed.How can i prevent from this issuse??

Comment: Is it closed or still opened?

Comment: it is closed but whenever i click on the page which means if i click some other place except modal pop up its closing thats my issue.it should not close if i click except modal.It should close only when i click cancel button or calling this  function hideModal()

Comment: @Vivekvetrri Can you please remove `ng-click='hideModal()'` attribute in the template on `ng-modal-overlay` `div` element and see what happens?

Comment: great man.sorry to miss communication..you are really awesome.Thank you so much

Comment: could you please refer this question if you donot mind      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404770/resetting-form-when-modalpop-up-gets-closed-if-i-click-any-place-in-my-page

Answer (score 0):

To stop click event add following code on background html tag:

```
ng-click="$event.preventDefault()"
```

See the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/2MWIpOs3uAG5EFQy6Ndn?p=preview

Comment: when i want to open modal popup i am using this code suppose if i put your code i am getting error.could you please explain where should i put this code?

Comment: You can use it like:   <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); 
                     selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>